# Privacy policy Apple (Facebook login). issue reported from Apple

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I got a message from Apple regarding below. I am using Facebook login Authentication as a part of login to app . What all procedure required to do to submit the app next time release.

Message given below,

Hello,

When you submitted your app, you answered questions about your app's privacy practices in App Store Connect. There are possible issues with the information you gave. You indicated that your app does not collect or track device or user data. However, your app integrates code from or communicates with third-parties that appear to collect and track this data, including, but not limited to, Facebook.

Comment: What does FaceBook tell you about user profiles and data collection?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try setting the key FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled (as Boolean) to false (0) on your info plist. That seems to keep the facebook SDK from automaticly collecting data that is tied to the users UUIDs on login.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Apple are scanning all apps in the App Store for some known SDK’s and comparing the results to the new App Store privacy declarations.
I have an app I haven’t updated since the Privacy Questionnaire appeared and thus haven’t completed it, yet Apple sent me this email too. Basically because they detected the app had an advertising SDK in it and I had to complete the privacy questions.

So Apple know your app is using the Facebook SDK and you have to either complete the privacy questionnaire in App Store Connect, or remove the SDK.
You can find more details on the Facebook SDK here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/10/22/preparing-for-apple-app-store-data-disclosure-requirements/